# Create a .zip file in Java with images

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I'm creating a Java program which gets images from a JFileChooser and create a .zip file containing the selected images. I get the files with this code:

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    fc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image files", "bmp", "png", "jpg")); 
    fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);  
    fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    File files[] = fc.getSelectedFiles();
```

How i create a .zip file containing the files of the `files[]` array?

Thank you for your help :D.

Comment: Use `ZipOutputStream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File someFile = new File("someFile.zip");
File files[] = fc.getSelectedFiles();
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(someFile));

// Create the ZIP file first
try (ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(bos)) {
    // Write files/copy to archive
    for (File file : files) {
        // Put a new ZIP entry to output stream for every file
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), out);
        out.closeEntry();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working, but the file created don't has the .zip entension

Comment: The file is called whatever you named it. Simply name it `someFile.zip`.